# How did Jack get back to Halloween land?

Tags: the-nightmare-before-christmas

In *The Nightmare Before Christmas*, Jack discovers a wooded area with doors leading to other holiday lands. When he goes through the Christmas door, he falls for quite a while, and then lands on a huge pile of snow.

He did not exit through a door in a tree, like the one he entered. How did he find his way back to Halloween land?

Comment: He drove back on that Christmas tractor, of course.

Comment: I have no canon backup (hence a comment, not an answer), but I always assumed that a major holiday figure, he always had the ability to return home at need. After he's shot down, for example, he simply opens a crypt to get there.  Again, no canon, but it is not inconsistent with such stories that he would have a way to open a portal back to his home.  How and where, could be holiday specific; for Jack a graveyard or perhaps haunted house.  For Santa, perhaps any chimney could do.  But in each case, a fairly common type of location. Now, finding one in Xmas land....

Comment: You forgot one very important thing, mate. He's Captain Jack Skellington.

Comment: @K-H-W The elves don't like to talk about the reindeer graveyard...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears (at least according to an [early draft](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/nightmare-b4-xmas_early.html) of the shooting script) that simply heading to the '***edge of town***' leads one to the clearing with the doors. Although it's not explicitly stated, it follows that simply heading out of Christmasland would achieve much the same effect:

> **EXT. EDGE OF FOREST. DAY/LATER.**
>
> Lock, Shock & Barrel head for the forest that Jack wandered through.
>
> [Singing]
>
> **They reach the very edge forest -- they are still in the light; one step ahead, it is dark and gloomy.**
>
> Lock, the natural-born leader of the three, stops in his tracks in the
>   last possible light.  The other two bump into him, in succession. 
>   Then all three crouch down at once.
>
> Beat.

---

Moving down the canon scale, The [Pearson Reader version](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119539.Tim_Burton_s_The_Nightmare_Before_Christmas) of the story (By Daphne Skinner) features an endpiece not seen in the film. It appears that one can simply *drive* from town to town without the use of a portal.

> *But for years after that night. Santa Claus sometimes left
>   Christmastown for an hour or two when he was bored with his happy
>   helpers and their happy songs. **When his life felt boring, he climbed
>   into his sleigh. He drove to Halloweentown and there he visited his
>   old friend Jack Skellington.** They talked about the year when Jack
>   wanted to be Santa Claus.*
>
> *Jack was always happy when Santa visited him. He liked to ask
>   questions about Christmastown and Santa liked to ask Jack about
>   Halloweentown. They could talk for hours and they were never bored*

Comment: [It's also in the movie's soundtrack as a closing song](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/n/nightmare_before_christmas/the_closing_song.html): (read it like Dr Seuss) So, many years later I thought I'd drop in, /
And there was old Jack still looking quite thin, /
With four or five skeleton children at hand /
Playing strange little tunes in their xylophone band. /  ... /
Would you do the whole thing all over again, / 
Knowing what you know now, knowing what you knew then? / 
And he smiled, like the old pumpkin king that I knew, / 
Then turned and asked softly of me, "Wouldn't you?"

Answer (score 6):

He never left through a door to leave Halloween, either.

Perhaps one who wanders far enough from  Town simply finds themselves in the woods - they act as a nexus connecting the towns.

The doors act as portals to a certain spot near each town, and return you there.

Answer (score 1):

## **How did Jack go from Halloween town to the doors in the first place?**

Before Jack opens the Christmas door and falls in, he already walked his way to the doors.
It's the same issue here. The movie has never specified it, but there is a strong implication that the Holiday Towns are all part of the same landmass.

So we know that there is a land connection between Halloween Town and the Holiday Doors. We've never **explicitly** seen a land connection between Christmas Town and the Holiday Doors, but this is implicitly confirmed by Jack entering Halloween town while riding a **snowmobile** that was clearly built in Christmas Town. He must have travelled over land from Christmas to Halloween.

## Come to think of it, there is another hidden implication in the movie.

- When Jack arrives at the doors, he has no idea what they mean. He is drawn to the drawing of the Christmas tree, but has no idea.
- Upon first seeing Christmas Town, Jack has **no idea** what Christmas is. He doesn't know the name, he doesn't know the intention of the holiday, he doesn't even know that other holidays existed in the first place. [**Jack doesn't know jack**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%20Don%27t%20Know%20Jack).

But Jack is later shown to know about other holidays:

- When Lock, Shock, and Barrel (Oogie's henchmen, the three kids) bring back the Easter Bunny, **Jack knows who the Easter Bunny is**.

Jack didn't show any knowledge about Easter when at the doors. So as I see it, there are only two explanations:

### 1. The inhabitants of Christmas Town could have explained the existence of holidays.

This also means that they probably gave him the snowmobile. And they could have told Jack how to get home.

However, this seems unlikely. Jack's misinterpretation of the meaning of Christmas somewhat hinges on the fact that it's Jack's *personal* (misguided) interpretation. If he talked to the citizens of Christmas Town, he would have asked them everything there is to know about Christmas, since he is so excited about it.

## 2. Jack did not find his way home immediately, and passed by Easter Town

This means that Jack stole the snowmobile (potentially because the Chrismas citizens were terrified by him, even if he was trying to be friendly) and travelled around, looking for a way to get home.

This makes much more sense. This explanation allows for the possibility that Jack never talked to the Christmas Town citizens, and therefore has never been explained what Christmas is.

While trying to find his way home, Jack must have come across Easter Town, where he learned about the Easter Bunny. Whether he merely observed it from a distance (similar to Christmas Town) or actually interacted with the inhabitants is of course completely unexplained in the movie.